# Filtering Table help / Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm trying to filter a table in excel by using integer values i have stored in a column on a sheet. The integer values exist in the table so I don't need to worry about filtering by a value that does not exist. I used the  record macro application and found that excel updates the table by using:

`Sheets("TEST_QUERY").ListObjects("SPC_QUERY").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= Array("4", "5"), Operator:=xlFilterValues`

The issue that I have is that I have a loop which can give me the array values that i store in a variant called FILTERS. the variable stores the values in the same format in the array (shows all the quotations and commas). 
When I replace the Array("4","5") with Array(FILTERS), **it does not filter**. 
I appreciate any help.

code so far..

```
Dim filters As String
Dim filters2 As Variant
Dim cel As Range

For Each cel In Range("HOD_Temp[Row Labels]")
    filters = cel.Value
    filters = filters & """" & cel.Value & """" & ","
Next cel
filters2 = Left(filters, Len(filters) - 1)


Sheets("TEST_QUERY").Activate
Sheets("TEST_QUERY").ListObjects("SPC_QUERY").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
    Array(filters2), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: I'm unclear whether your `FILTERS` variable is an array (in which case, why use `Array(FILTERS)`, why not just use `FILTERS`) or whether it is a string variable which is something like `"""4"", ""5"""` (in which case that's just one element and is not the two strings `"4"` and `"5"`)

Comment: It might be best if you include into the question the code you are using to `Dim FILTERS` and the code you are using to assign values to it.

Comment: the FILTERS  variable is not an array and i understand that the way i am using the variable, the value is one string. would i need to split the string by each comma and store it in an array called new_array and then use that array to filter on?

Comment: That's a possible way, but if you post your code that generates `FILTERS`, it may be able to be done in an easier way.

Comment: i updated my post with the loop i use to create the string

Comment: Have you tried using `Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(Range("HOD_Temp[Row Labels]"))`?  If that works, it would be much simpler than creating your own array.

Comment: Just tested a normal filter using a normal range for the criteria (i.e. not using Excel tables for either bit) and it works providing the data in the criteria range is stored in the cells as a text value.  So will that work for you?  If not, we can show you how to create an array instead of appending strings to a longer string.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help...all i had to do was change the data type in that column to text...

Answer (score 1):

After some discussion in comments, it was decided that this could be simplified to

```
Sheets("TEST_QUERY").ListObjects("SPC_QUERY").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
    Application.Transpose(Range("HOD_Temp[Row Labels]")), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

thus bypassing the need to set up a special variable.